# A tip on mysql timestamp datatype

Tags: php, mysql, date, timestamp

Need to know how to deal with a mysql timestamp field .. 
I mean When I add a new date into PHPMYADMIN .. and the field is timestamp .. it saves a readable date .I find this strange as I know that timestamp is supposed to be integr .It is the integer that represents number of seconds passed since 01-01-1970 till this date .

And if this is logical .. from my php script what shall I send to the database to save in this mysql timestamp field ?
Thank you so much

Comment: You're specifically saving a *time*, and MySQL is kind enough to show it to you in a readable format, because it knows it's a time. If you'd just want an integer, using an `INT` column would do it.

Comment: **Unix** timestamps are integers. MySQL's TIMESTAMP data type is not (not at least from the user perspective).

Answer (score 1):

Mysql Timestamp format is YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS .And it ranges from 1970-01-01 00:00:01 to 2038-01-19 03:14:07 .For saving unix timestamp in mysql you need to use INT as datatype

Answer (score 1):

> `TIMESTAMP` columns are displayed in the same format as `DATETIME` columns. In other words, the display width is fixed at 19 characters, and the format is `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS`.

Reference: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/timestamp.html